Find all Parent and Child from Child relationships with isCascadeDelete == true
Let's say i can retrieve it this way
for(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result : Schema.describeSObjects(new String[]{'Account'})) {
for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr  : result.getChildRelationships()){
    if(cr.isCascadeDelete() && cr.getChildSObject().toString() == 'Contact') {
        system.debug(cr);
        system.debug(cr.getChildSObject());
    }
}
}

but is it possible to get it somehow without leveraging all the entries (maybe some SOQL)?

No. Iterating through the child relationships is the correct, and only, way to get this information, in Apex or in any other external format (e.g. the REST API).
